# Including additional claims within Access Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am following IdentityServer 4 samples for a JS SPA calling a backend API.  All is working however within the API (.NET CORE) I am getting the access token from the js client.  At this moment, I am able to use the userinfo end point (on the Identity Server) to capture more information about the user.  This is working fine.
The problem/question is that for each API call I must call this userinfo endpoint to identify the user as the Access Token alone does not have user information.

What is the recommendation when working with Access Tokens and backend APIs(from JS Client).  Suggestions are
a) Continue to make calls the UserInfo end point on each API call (this seems to be performance issue)
b) Send user information with the ajax request as parameter or another header information (seems insecure)
c) Do some sort of caching on the API server for access token to user relationship (doesn't feel right)
d) Figure out how to add user information within the Access Token.  I have read that it is not wise to include user information with an access token

Are there other options?

My scenario seems quite common with a JavaScript client accessing a backend API and needing to know user information.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to keep the ID/access access tokens small, especially if you have the SaveTokens=true, then your asp.net core session cookie will be very big!

Better to lookup the user details from the user info endpoint and then cache it.

Why do you need to call the UserInfo endpoint on every API request?

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't provided any sample code here I am assuming that in your .NET API you are using the below code to validate the token.

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect(Authentication.OidcAuthenticationScheme, 
 options =>
  {
   options.Authority = "IdS4 URL";
   options.SaveTokens = true;
   options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
  });
```

If that is the case then yes your API would call the `connect/userinfo` endpoint on each request to get additional claims and it would be one round trip to the ID4 token provider.

Answer to your question/concern about adding user information in the access token: Actually it depends upon what kind of information you are trying to put in the access token. If it isn't PII then I would suggest adding the information in the access token itself and use `.AddIdentityServerAuthentication()` middleware for token validation.

e.g

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
          //ToDo: Add your configuration here
        });
```

I hope this answer will help you!

Comment: I wouldn't use the IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation library anymore. [From the official Github site:](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation) "This library is deprecated and not being maintained anymore.". [Use one of these approachs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html#protecting-apis) instead.

Comment: @Alpha75 I agree with you, I just wanted to move away from `.AddOpenIdConnect()` extension method, either use `.AddIdentityServerAuthentication()` or `.AddJwtBearer()`. Initially I was facing multiple issues where this extension validates identity token and not access token.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with designing the claims you want to use in your API. Claims don't always need to be included in the access token and returned to the client though. Eg it is possible to return an opaque reference token or for it to be a small JWT. As Tore says, I would aim to keep the access token small and confidential.

Usually some form of claims caching is used, in one of these locations. The solution you choose often depends on how sophisticated your middleware is.

- Authorization Server
- API Gateway
- API

My [API Authorization Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/) may give you some ideas that you can use for your own solution. My [.Net Core API](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore) uses a Custom Authentication Handler to do Claims Caching in the API itself, since I am working with AWS Cognito, which has very limited access token features.